# Facebook custom tabs (iframe) linking to other FB apps/content in main window?

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs, facebook-iframe

Strange request - I know this wouldn't normally work with a typical iframe situation... but wondering if Facebook have done anything to allow for this.

I have a client who is loading a custom page into an iframe on their facebook page. Within the iframe(d) content they want to link to other pages within their facebook for polls etc.
Is there anything built into FB's platform that would allow me to code these links such that they redirect the main Facebook window rather than the iframe itself?

Also - anyone have any clues how to 'like' the main page from content pulled into the iframe?

Sorry if these are stupid questions - but have spent the afternoon finding nothing of use on Google. So used to FBML now I'm almost missing it now it's no longer usable,

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to break out of the iFrame? You should just be able to link outside of the iFrame by setting target="_top" on the link. This will break out of the frame you are in. For example

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/page" target="_top">Link</a>
```

You should also be able to Like a page on Facebook just by supplying the URL to the like button here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

or you can use target="_parent"

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/page" target="_parent">Link</a>
```